# Installing corosync and pacemaker on Amazon EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos7, pacemaker

I'm trying to setup a HA cluster for 2 amazon instances. The OS of my instances is CentOS7.

```
Hostnames:
master1.example.com
master2.example.com

IP internal:
10.0.0.x1
10.0.0.x2

IP public:
52.19.x.x
52.18.x.x
```

I'm following this tutorial:
http://jensd.be/156/linux/building-a-high-available-failover-cluster-with-pacemaker-corosync-pcs

```
[root@master1 centos]# pcs status nodes
Pacemaker Nodes:
 Online: master1.example.com 
 Standby: 
 Offline: master2.example.com
```

while my master 2 is showing the following

```
[root@master2 centos]# pcs status nodes
Pacemaker Nodes:
 Online: master2.example.com 
 Standby: 
 Offline: master1.example.com
```

- But they should be online, both.
  What am I doing wrong?
- Which IP do I have to choose as Virtual IP? Because the IP's are not in the same subnet.

Answer (score 2):

Change you security group rules to allow inbound and outbound tcp & https traffic between all cluster nodes. That should do it. (pretty old question but unanswered so thought someone might need it).